# Lisp function that recursively adds elements to a list

Tags: lisp

I working on a lisp function that will accept two parameters, the second of which is a list.  It will take the first parameter and add it after every element of the second parameter.  This is as far as I got:

```
(defun rd(list n1 lis2)
  (rd ((n1) (cdr (lis2))))
  (cons (n1) (cons (car (lis2))))
  )
```

If the two parameters are `'aa` and `'(b c d f)`, the desired output should be: `aa b aa c aa d aa f aa`

Comment: You seem to have some basic syntax problems. `(n1)` is a call to the `n1` function.

Comment: But `n1` isn't a function.

Comment: Is it added after or before each element of the list? You have `aa` at the beginning and end of your result.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put variables inside `()`, that's for calling functions.

If the function takes two parameters, the parameter list should just be `(n1 lis2)`, no need for `list` before that.

You're not doing anything with the result of the recursive call. You need to combine it with `n1` and the first element of `lis2`.

A recursive function has to check for the base case, otherwise it will recurse infinitely.

```
(defun rd (n1 lis2)
  (if (null lis2)
      (list n1) ;; Add n1 at the end
      (list* n1 (car lis2) (rd n1 (cdr lis2))))) ;; put n1 before every element

(rd 'aa '(1 2 3 4 5)) ;; => (aa 1 aa 2 aa 3 aa 4 aa 5 aa)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want insert the element **after** each head of the input list:

```lisp
(defun f (a l)
    (cond
        ((null l) l)
        (T (cons (car l) (cons a (f a (cdr l)))))
    )
)
```

```lisp
(format t "~a" (f 'aa '(1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6)))

(1 AA 2 AA 3 AA 3 AA 4 AA 5 AA 5 AA 6 AA)
```

In this case, if `l` is an empty list, the output will be `NIL`.

Otherwise if you want insert the element **before** every tail of the list (included the last tail, i.e. the empty list)

```lisp
(defun f (a l)
    (cond
        ((null l) (list a))
        (T (cons a (cons (car l) (f a (cdr l)))))
    )
)
```

In this case:

```lisp
(format t "~a" (f 'aa '(1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6)))

(AA 1 AA 2 AA 3 AA 3 AA 4 AA 5 AA 5 AA 6 AA)
```

If `l` is an empty list, the output will be the list `(aa)`.